# String.replace() not working, even though the same regex does in other langs?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textarea element which contains text in this form:

```
 215
 00:10:38,810 --> 00:10:40,040
 [ROBIN LAUGHING]

 216
 00:10:40,370 --> 00:10:41,330
 [ALL SCREAMING]
```

I take that text and run `replace(/^[\d\s-:,>]+$/g, '');` on it, and then console.log the result. But I see the unchanged result instead of any change.

I have tried the same regex on the same text using Ruby' `String#gsub` method and it does exactly what I want it to. I'm a little confused as to what JavaScript is doing differently.

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you need the multiline flag on the regex?

Comment: @GreenTriangle You do know that `replace()` *returns* the modified string, but leaves the original untouched, right?

Comment: Are you aware that Javascript's `string.replace` returns a modified copy of the string, rather than modifying the original? (`gsub` does too, but maybe you were using `gsub!` or you forgot the assignment in only one language.)

Comment: Note that `-` should always be at the edge of a character class: `[\d\s:,>-]`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that `replace` returns a new string. I'm running `console.log(input.replace)`. I expect it to strip the lines consisting of only numbers and timestamps, leaving [ROBIN LAUGHING] and [ALL SCREAMING] behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regexp `/^[\d\s\-:,>]+$/mg` instead the one you used.

Also, keep in mind that .replace will keep the original string unchanged, so you should do something like:

```
myString = myString.replace(/^[\d\s\-:,>]+$/mg, "");
```

Comment: This does work, but I'm not trying to strip all numbers, colons, and whitespace from the text, which is what it does; I'm only trying to remove *lines that solely consist of those things* (thus the `^...$` form).

Comment: In that case, check my edited reply. Hope this one helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, the edit makes it work perfectly. I wasn't aware of the `m` flag, I learnt something. Thank you.